exec ./mvnw: no such file or directory after running docker-compose up in spring boot
I build a spring boot application. I am learning docker. Windows 11 on my machine
I try to run docker-compose up but it fails to find ./mwnw.
Two other developpers share the same configuration and the application starts correctly (one linux user and one windows user). From my side it fails with the error below.
I have read it could be a conversion issue between crlf and lf but not sure.
I also have the following permission on files :
// ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 olivi 197121 11598 Apr 16 17:53 mvnw
-rw-r--r-- 1 olivi 197121  7797 Dec 22 16:16 mvnw.cmd

Any help will be appreciated.
Error :

docker-compose.yaml :
version: '3.8'

services:
  db-mysql-mtgbox:
    container_name: db-mysql-mtgbox
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'qwerty'
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}
    volumes:
      - db-mysql-mtgbox:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=${APP_SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${APP_SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${APP_SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=${APP_SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO}
      - JWT_SECRETKEY= ${JWT_SECRETKEY}
      - JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITYTIMEINMINUTE= ${JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITYTIMEINMINUTE}
    depends_on:
      - db-mysql-mtgbox
    volumes:
      - ..:/app
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2

volumes:
  db-mysql-mtgbox:

Dockerfile :
FROM amazoncorretto:21
WORKDIR /app
CMD [ "./mvnw", "spring-boot:run" ]


Your image doesn't actually seem to contain the application.  Do you need to COPY the application source code in and build it?  What code produces the image file you show; is there a plain-text error message?

@DavidMaze I'm not able to provide an answer for this as I'm still getting acquainted with Docker. My files are located within a Docker folder at the root of the application (dockerfile, docker-compose.yaml, .env, .gitignore). I suspect that some configuration settings are responsible for copying the application. I made it work (see my answer)

The issue indeed stemmed from the crlf / lf conversion in ./mwnw. It seems the file wasn't readable due to this. I had to convert it from DOS to Unix format to resolve the problem. While some resources suggest using the dos2unix or unix2dos tool, I found that a straightforward online converter did the job for me. Hopefully, this solution might help others. If anyone has a more precise explanation, please feel free to correct me.
